# Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, null-pointer

I am doing a Custom Search Page, with AND and OR Statements on the Emailmessage Object.  The Search function on the email message object works correctly, however I get  a null pointer Exception if I search with account or contact criteria.

If I switch part of the query to

```
AND (Accountid IN:ACCids  OR ContactId IN:Contids)
```

Instead of OR, the account and contact query works correctly, but the email message fails to work without the account being queried.

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class SearchCaseEmailController {
Public List<case> ListOfcasesResult {get;set;}

public EmailMessage emailMessRef{get;set;}
public List<EmailMessage> emailMessageList{get;set;}
public String emailBody{get;set;}
public Date FromDate{get;set;}
public Date ToDate{get;set;}
public String contactName{get;set;}
public String contactEmailAddress{get;set;}
public String accountName{get;set;}
public String customerAccNumber{get;set;}
public String groupNumber{get;set;}
public String accNumFilter {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> filterCondition{get;set;}
public String emailFromAddFilter{get;set;}
public String emailSubFilter{get;set;}
public String emailToAddFilter{get;set;}
public String emailBodyFilter{get;set;}
public String emailccFilter{get;set;}
public String contactNameFilter{get;set;}
public String accNameFilter{get;set;}
public String accNumberFilter{get;set;}
public List<Account> accountQuery{get;set;}
public List<Account> tempList{get;set;}
public List<EmailWrapper> EmailList {get;set;}




public SearchCaseEmailController(){

    emailMessageList = new List<EmailMessage>();
    emailMessRef = new EmailMessage();
    filterCondition = new List<SelectOption>();
    filterCondition.add(new SelectOption('AND','AND'));
    filterCondition.add(new SelectOption('OR','OR'));



}  
public pageReference fetchAccountSpecificCases(){ 
    Set<ID> SUBids = fetchEmailmessageIDS();
    Set<ID> ACCids =fetchAccountIDS();
    Set<ID> Contids =fetchContactIDS();
    ListOfcasesResult = new List<case>();
    EmailList = new List<EmailWrapper>();


    List<EmailMessage> emList = [SELECT Id,FromAddress,ToAddress,CcAddress ,Subject, Parentid,Textbody,MessageDate FROM EmailMessage WHERE id IN:SUBids  LIMIT 100];
    Map<Id,List<EmailMessage>> caseIdToEmails = new Map<Id,List<EmailMessage>>();
    if(!emList.isEmpty()){
        for(EmailMessage em : emList){
            if(caseIdToEmails.containsKey(em.ParentId)){
                caseIdToEmails.get(em.ParentId).add(em);
            }
            else{
                caseIdToEmails.put(em.ParentId,new List<EmailMessage>{em});
            }
        }

        List<Case> caseList = [SELECT id, Account.Name, Accountid,contactId,Contact.Name, caseNumber from Case WHERE Id IN :caseIdToEmails.keySet() OR (Accountid IN:ACCids  OR ContactId IN:Contids)  LIMIT 50];

        for(Case c : caseList){

            for(EmailMessage em : caseIdToEmails.get(c.Id)){

                EmailWrapper ew = new EmailWrapper();
                ew.emailId = em.id;                    
                ew.emailFrom = em.FromAddress;                 
                ew.emailTo = em.ToAddress;                   
                ew.emailCC = em.CcAddress;                   
                ew.subjectLine = em.Subject;                    
                ew.emailBody = em.TextBody;                    
                ew.caseId = c.id;                   
                ew.accountId = c.AccountId;                 
                ew.contactId = c.ContactId;                  
                ew.accountName = c.Account.Name;                  
                ew.contactName = c.Contact.Name;                 
                ew.CaseNumber = c.CaseNumber;
                EmailList.add(ew);

            }
        }
    }

    system.debug('Result of Account IDs'+ACCids);
    system.debug('Result of Contact IDs'+Contids);
    system.debug('DateFrom'+FromDate);
    system.debug('DateTo'+ToDate);
    //  ListOfcasesResult = [SELECT ID,Subject,Account.name,Contact.Name, caseNumber, (SELECT Id,FromAddress,ToAddress,CcAddress ,Subject, textbody FROM EmailMessages) FROM CASE WHERE AccountId IN:ACCids  OR ContactId IN:Contids  LIMIT 100];


    return null;
}

public class EmailWrapper{
    public String caseNumber{get;set;}
    public String emailId{get;set;}
    public String emailFrom {get;set;}
    public String emailTo {get;set;}
    public String emailCC {get;set;}
    public String subjectLine{get;set;}
    public String emailBody {get;set;}
    public String caseId{get;set;}
    public Case cases{get;set;}
    public String accountName{get;set;}
    public String accountId{get;set;}
    public String contactId{get;set;}
    public String contactName {get;set;}

}



public PageReference searchCaseEmails(){ 

    fetchAccountSpecificCases();

    return null;
}

Set<ID> EmailmessageIDS;                                                        //Fetching Query Subject
public Set<ID> fetchEmailmessageIDS(){
    EmailMessageIDS = new set<ID>();
    String subjectQuery = 'select Id from EmailMessage where id != null ';
    if((EmailMessRef.Subject !='' && EmailMessRef.Subject !=null) || (EmailMessRef.FromAddress !='' && EmailMessRef.FromAddress !=null)  || (EmailMessRef.ToAddress !='' && EmailMessRef.ToAddress !=null)  || (EmailMessRef.ccAddress !='' && EmailMessRef.ccAddress !=null)){

        System.debug('------------subject------: '+ EmailMessRef.Subject);
        System.debug('----FromAddress--------'+ EmailMessRef.FromAddress);
        System.debug('----Fromdate------'+ FromDate);
        System.debug('----Fromdate------'+ toDate);
        if(EmailMessRef.Subject != null  ){
            if(EmailMessRef.Subject.contains('*')){
                EmailMessRef.Subject = EmailMessRef.Subject.replace('*','');
                subjectQuery += emailsubfilter+' Subject LIKE  \'%'+EmailMessRef.Subject+'%\' ';
            }else{
                subjectQuery += emailsubfilter+' Subject = \''+EmailMessRef.Subject+'\' ';
                System.debug('----subject--------'+ EmailMessRef.Subject);
            }

        }

        if(EmailMessRef.fromAddress != null  ){
            if(EmailMessRef.fromAddress.contains('*')){
                EmailMessRef.FromAddress = EmailMessRef.FromAddress.replace('*','');
                subjectQuery += emailFromAddFilter+' fromAddress LIKE  \'%'+EmailMessRef.FromAddress+'%\' ';
            }else{
                subjectQuery += emailFromAddFilter+' FromAddress = \''+EmailMessRef.FromAddress+'\' ';
                System.debug('----FromAddress--------'+ EmailMessRef.FromAddress);
            }

        }
        if(EmailMessRef.ToAddress != null  ){
            if(EmailMessRef.ToAddress.contains('*')){
                EmailMessRef.ToAddress = EmailMessRef.ToAddress.replace('*','');
                subjectQuery += emailtoaddfilter+' toAddress LIKE  \'%'+EmailMessRef.ToAddress+'%\' ';
            }else{
                subjectQuery += emailtoaddfilter+' ToAddress = \''+EmailMessRef.ToAddress+'\' ';
                System.debug('----ToAddress--------'+ EmailMessRef.ToAddress);
            }

        }
        if(EmailMessRef.ccAddress != null  ){
            if(EmailMessRef.ccAddress.contains('*')){
                EmailMessRef.ccAddress = EmailMessRef.ccAddress.replace('*','');
                subjectQuery += emailccFilter+' ccAddress LIKE  \'%'+EmailMessRef.ccAddress+'%\'';
            }else{
                subjectQuery += emailccFilter+' ccAddress = \''+EmailMessRef.ccAddress+'\'';
                System.debug('----ccAddress--------'+ EmailMessRef.ccAddress);
            }

        } 


        System.debug('subjectresult list----------------'+ subjectQuery.replaceFirst(' id != null AND| id != null OR', ''));
        List<EmailMessage> subjectResult = database.query(subjectQuery.replaceFirst(' id != null AND| id != null OR', ''));

        for(EmailMessage ee:subjectResult){
            EmailmessageIDS.add(ee.id);
        }
    }else{
        subjectQuery = 'select Id from EmailMessage ';
        List<EmailMessage> subjectResult = database.query(subjectQuery);

        for(EmailMessage ee:subjectResult){
            EmailmessageIDS.add(ee.id);

        }
    }
    System.debug('Emailmessageids ---------------------'+ EmailmessageIDS);
    return EmailmessageIDS;

}


Set<ID> ContactIDS;
public Set<ID> fetchContactIDS(){ 
    ContactIDS = new Set<ID>();                             //Fetching Query Contacts
    System.debug('fetchContactSpecificCases=====');
    System.debug('=======contactName ===== :'+contactName );
    System.debug('=======contactEmailAddress========== :'+contactEmailAddress);
    String contactQuery = 'select Id from Contact where contact.name != null ';
    if((contactName !='' && contactName !=null) || (contactEmailAddress !='' && contactEmailAddress !=null)){


        System.debug('=======Entry contactName ========== :'+contactName );


        // APPEND CONTACT NAME
        if(contactName != null && contactName !=null ){
            if(contactName.contains('*')){
                contactName = contactName.replace('*','');
                contactQuery += ' and Name LIKE  \'%'+contactName+'%\'';
            }else{
                contactQuery += ' and Name = \''+contactName+'\'';
            }
        }
        if((contactName != '' &&  contactName !=null) && (contactEmailAddress != '' && contactEmailAddress!=null)){
            contactQuery += ' '+contactNameFilter+' ';
        }

        // APPEND CONTACT EMAIL
        if(contactEmailAddress != '' && contactEmailAddress !=null){
            if(contactEmailAddress.contains('*')){
                contactEmailAddress = contactEmailAddress.replace('*','');
                contactQuery += ' and Email LIKE \'%'+contactEmailAddress+'%\'';
            }else{
                contactQuery += ' and Email = \''+contactEmailAddress+'\'';
            }

        }
        System.debug('**************contactQuery===='+contactQuery);

        List<Contact> contactResult = database.query(contactQuery);
        System.debug('**************contactQuery===='+contactResult);
        for(contact cc:contactResult){
            ContactIDS.add(cc.id);

        }



        System.debug('contactQuery===='+contactResult);
        System.debug('contactQuery ID===='+ContactIDS);

    }
    return ContactIDS;
}


Set<ID> AccountIds = new Set<ID>();
public Set<ID> fetchAccountIDS(){                              //Fetching Query Accounts
    System.debug('fetchContactSpecificCases=====');
    String accountQuery = 'select Id from Account where ';

    if((accountName!= '' && accountName !=null) || (groupNumber !='' && groupNumber !=null) || (customerAccNumber !='' && customerAccNumber !='') ){

        if(accountName !='' && groupNumber !='' && customerAccNumber !='' ){
            if(accountName.contains('*')){
                accountName = accountName.replace('*','');
                accountQuery += ' Name LIKE \'%' + accountName + '%\'';
            }else{
                accountQuery += ' Name = \''+accountName+'\'';
            }
            accountQuery += ' '+accNameFilter+' ';
            if(customerAccNumber.contains('*')){
                customerAccNumber = customerAccNumber.replace('*','');

                accountQuery += ' Customer_Account_Number__c LIKE \'%' + customerAccNumber + '%\'';
            }else{
                accountQuery += ' Customer_Account_Number__c = \''+customerAccNumber +'\'';
            }

            accountQuery += ' '+accNumberFilter+' ';
            if(groupNumber.contains('*')){
                groupNumber = groupNumber .replace('*','');

                accountQuery += ' Group_ID__c LIKE \'%' + groupNumber + '%\'';
            }else{
                accountQuery += 'Group_ID__c = \''+groupNumber +'\'';
            }    

        }else if((accountName!= '' && accountName !=null) && (groupNumber =='' || groupNumber ==null) && (customerAccNumber =='' || customerAccNumber ==null)){
            if(accountName.contains('*')){
                accountName = accountName.replace('*','');
                accountQuery += ' Name LIKE \'%' + accountName + '%\'';
            }else{
                accountQuery += ' Name = \''+accountName+'\'';
            }
        }else if(customerAccNumber  != '' && groupNumber =='' && accountName ==''){
            if(customerAccNumber.contains('*')){
                customerAccNumber = customerAccNumber.replace('*','');

                accountQuery += ' Customer_Account_Number__c LIKE \'%' + customerAccNumber + '%\'';
            }else{
                accountQuery += ' Customer_Account_Number__c = \''+customerAccNumber +'\'';
            }

        }else if(customerAccNumber  == '' && groupNumber !='' && accountName ==''){
            if(groupNumber.contains('*')){
                groupNumber = groupNumber .replace('*','');

                accountQuery += ' Group_ID__c LIKE \'%' + groupNumber + '%\'';
            }else{
                accountQuery += 'Group_ID__c = \''+groupNumber +'\'';
            }

        }else if((accountName != '' && accountName != null) && ((customerAccNumber != '' && customerAccNumber != null) || (groupNumber !=null && groupNumber !='')) ){
            if((accountName != '' && accountName != null) && (customerAccNumber != '' && customerAccNumber != null) ){
                if(accountName.contains('*')){
                    accountName = accountName.replace('*','');
                    accountQuery += ' Name LIKE \'%' + accountName + '%\'';
                }else{
                    accountQuery += ' Name = \''+accountName+'\'';
                }


                accountQuery += ' '+accNameFilter+' ';

                if(customerAccNumber.contains('*')){
                    customerAccNumber = customerAccNumber.replace('*','');

                    accountQuery += ' Customer_Account_Number__c LIKE \'%' + customerAccNumber + '%\'';
                }else{
                    accountQuery += ' Customer_Account_Number__c = \''+customerAccNumber +'\'';
                }


            }else if((accountName != '' && accountName != null) && (groupNumber != '' && groupNumber != null) ){
                if(accountName.contains('*')){
                    accountName = accountName.replace('*','');
                    accountQuery += ' Name LIKE \'%' + accountName + '%\'';
                }else{
                    accountQuery += ' Name = \''+accountName+'\'';
                }


                accountQuery += ' '+accNameFilter+' ';

                if(groupNumber.contains('*')){
                    groupNumber = groupNumber .replace('*','');

                    accountQuery += ' Group_ID__c LIKE \'%' + groupNumber + '%\'';
                }else{
                    accountQuery += 'Group_ID__c = \''+groupNumber +'\'';
                }


            }
        }
        System.debug('accountQuery ===='+accountQuery );

        List<Account> accountResult = database.query(accountQuery);
        for(Account acc:accountResult){
            AccountIds.add(acc.id);
        }

    }
    return AccountIds;
}
```

I still need to update the filter criteria as seen in the subject.

The error occurs on

> Error is in expression '{!searchCaseEmails}' in page searchcaseemails:
>   Class.SearchCaseEmailController.fetchAccountSpecificCases: line 66, column 1
>   Class.SearchCaseEmailController.searchCaseEmails: line 118, column 1

Comment: did you get the line number on which error is occurring?

Comment: You didn't include the `fetchEmailMessageIds` method in your post here...Please [edit] your question to include that method as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes each `Case` will have `EmailMessage` records related to it. The solution is to check if the `List<EmailMessage>` is non-null before iterating over it.

I recommend you break out your `for` loop into a distinct method to simplify your code and testing. This strategy is simply focusing on *Separation Of Concerns* using *Function Composition*. You can compose simpler functions here as follows:

```
public static List<EmailWrapper> buildWrappers(Case record, List<EmailMessage> emails)
{
    List<EmailWrapper> wrappers = new List<EmailWrapper>();
    if (emails == null) return wrappers;

    for (EmailMessage email : emails)
        wrappers.add(buildWrapper(record, email));
    return wrappers;
}
public static EmailWrapper buildWrapper(Case record, EmailMessage email)
{
    // build single EmailWrapper instance based on your innermost loop
}
```

Then in your `fetchAccountSpecificCases` method, simply loop through the `Case` records and pass them to this delegated logic which performs a null check:

```
for (Case record : caseList)
    emailList.addAll(buildWrappers(record, caseIdToEmails.get(record.Id));
```

One more note on how you can tighten your code, I usually use a more compact grouping loop:

```
Map<Id, List<EmailMessage>> caseIdToEmails = new Map<Id, List<EmailMessage>>();
for (EmailMessage email : [SELECT ... FROM EmailMessage WHERE ...])
{
    if (!caseIdToEmails.containsKey(email.ParentId))
        caseIdToEmails.put(email.ParentId, new List<EmailMessage>();
    caseIdtoEmails.get(email.ParentId).add(email);
}
```